# Is it possible to super fast-track an application for a Taiwanese citizen to visit the US?

Tags: visas, usa, taiwanese-citizens

**Short version:** If a Taiwanese citizen with a current passport and a clean prior travel record and who has had prior visits to the US wants to visit the US to attend a wedding, is there a way of expediting the normal US application process and what is the minimum time liable to be required?

---

**Longer version:**

A friend who is a Taiwanese citizen and who lives in Taipei told me previously that she would be attending a friend's wedding in the US (California,) but a few days ago said that she was not able to do so, as she had since found that the time required to obtain entry permission to the US for a Taiwanese citizen was excessive. The wedding is late January - say 2+ weeks from now. I understand that the 'bottleneck' is gaining US approval, not at the Taiwanese end.

I suggested to her that there are usually (official and legal) fast track processes available for those willing to pay extra $, but she was unaware of such being available in this case. I could wade into the available internet information available but hopefully someone here is aware of the specific situation.

Comment: As a Taiwanese citizen, she can visit the US under the visa waiver program. Why is she required to apply for a visa in advance?